# How to access netsted json array elements using Boost in c++

Tags: json, linux, c++11, boost

Below is the json array which i am parsing in my code  in order to populate the **parameterList**  array data but not sure why it is not working and i am not able to access the elements of nested array paramList.

```
{
"packageList" :[    {
            "arcValue" : "Bond",
            "parameterList" : [ {"key1" : "value1",
                        "key2" : "value2",
                        "key3" : "value3"
                                 },

                        {"key4" : "value4",
                        "key5" : "value5",
                        "key6" : "value6"


                         }
                  ]


            },

                       {
            "arcValue" : "Bond1",
            "parameterList" : [ {"max" : "value1",
                        "rgb" : "value2",
                        "depth" : "value3"
                                },

                               {"max1" : "value4",
                                "max2" : "value5",
                                "max3" : "value6"

                                }
                          ]


            }

                 ]    

}
```

**Below is the code snippet for the same**:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include<list>
#include <vector>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

struct Config {
    std::string name;
    std::list<std::vector<std::string>> parameters;
};

std::list<std::vector<std::string>> parse_config(std::string const& fname) {

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    std::ifstream file(fname);
    boost::property_tree::read_json(file, pt);
    Config config;

    for (auto& v : pt.get_child("packageList"))
    {
        auto& node = v.second;

        config.name = node.get("arcValue", "");
        std::cout<<config.name;

       for(auto &param :node.get_child("parameterList"))
        {
          config.parameters.push_back({config.name,param.first,param.second.get_value("")});

         }   

    }

    return config.parameters;
}


int main() {

    std::list<std::vector<std::string>> vec = parse_config("sample2");

for (auto &v : vec)
{

    for (auto const &i : v)

        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;

}


}
```

Basically in above code all the param related with arcValue (i.e Bond,Bond1)needs to be inserted in list of vector and later on same needs to be inserted in config file through API interface. 
/*Bond related information needs to inserted from list of vector  to Bond config file*/

```
structure.svc.parameters.push_back({"Bond","value1","value2","value3"});
structure.svc.parameters.push_back({"Bond","value4","value5","value6"});
```

/*Bond1 related parameter information needs to inserted from list to Bond1 config file*/

```
structure.svc.parameters.push_back({"Bond1","value1","value2","value3"});
structure.svc.parameters.push_back({"Bond1","value4","value5","value6"});
```

Apart from this in current implementation both Bond and Bond1 are being inserted in same list along with parameters. Can anybody suggest is this right approach or same can be implemented with better way ?
As per my requirement Bond and  Bond1 parameters needs to be inserted in separate config file through API interface but in current implementation both are clubbed altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate one more time to get the nested array data in order to populate the nested array.
Here is the code snippet.

```
for( auto &param : node.get_child("parameterList") )
{  
    for( const auto& itr : param.second )
    {
         config.parameters.push_back( {config.name,itr.second.get_value("")} );
    }
}
```

Below is the output:

```
BondBond1Bond
value1
Bond
value2
Bond
value3
Bond
value4
Bond
value5
Bond
value6
Bond1
value1
Bond1
value2
Bond1
value3
Bond1
value4
Bond1
value5
Bond1
value6
```

Comment: Thanks for update. Apart from this as I discussed in my question regarding design strategy , insertion should take in below order  with four columns and multiple rows.(i.e .Bond","value1","value2","value3" ) . Could u suggest any  design for the same.